# Is there any way to say to TThread.synchronize to fail after waiting more than xxx seconds?

Tags: delphi

Sometimes when you call `TThread.synchronize` you can deadlock. Is there any way to say that if `TThread.synchronize` takes more than 250 ms to acquire the main UI thread then it should fail? (something that we have for example with `Tmonitor`)

Comment: Why don't you just fix the defect in your code that leads to the deadlock?

Comment: This is like saying "My car has a flat tire, what can I put on my tire so it doesn't look flat anymore?" when the appropriate solution is to repair/replace the tire.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yes I can redraw the code but here i speak on pure theory if their in not in TThread.synchronize the equivalent we have with Tmonitor.enter

Comment: You are drawing a false equivalence, these two methods aren't comparable. Stop writing code that can deadlock. TMonitor can deadlock too and a timeout won't help.

Comment: have you looked at this [SO q:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958353/deadlock-delphi-explanation-solution)?  The answer describes some common threading deadlock situations and how to avoid them.

Comment: @JerryDodge thanks for your help! To make you better understand, I update the question to show how I enter the deadlock. now that you know the reason how you will fix it without making a timeout to TThread.Synchronize?

Comment: @MartynA thanks for your help! I update the question to show how I enter the deadlock But I think the only way out i have is to timeout the synchronize

Comment: If your deadlocking problem arises between calls to `synchronize` from different threads, under Windows couldn't you make the threads to acquire a `CriticalSection` before entering the `Synchronize` call?  That way, they couldn't both execute `Synchronize` at the same time. I'm not sure about iOS or Android, but would have thought they have a similar thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is that `TThread.Synchronize` does not support a timeout.

However, the real problem is the defect that leads to the deadlock in your program. When you write a program that deadlocks, the way forward is to identify the cause of the deadlock and to fix the defect. You cannot hope to make progress by ignoring such defects.

Comment: thanks for your help! To make you better understand, I update the question to show how I enter the deadlock. now that you know the reason how you will fix it without making a timeout to  TThread.Synchronize?

Comment: I reverted the change. If you'd like to ask a new question about your deadlock that needs to be a new question. If you do that though, make sure you give a good [mcve].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828360/about-deadlock-with-tthread-synchronize

Comment: bah yes it does not support a timeout :( but I was more hoping a way out in an answer, ut seems there is no way out so it's the good answer :)