# About deadlock with TThread.synchronize

Tags: delphi

I use a library (WebRTC), that fire all event in one of its own and opaque background thread. So this is the flow I m facing :

```
:: MainUIThread
fMyWeRTC.doSomeThink;

:: WebRTC own and opaque background Thread
Procedure fMyWebRTC.renderFrame(frame: TRTCFrame);
begin
  TThread.synchronize(nil,
  procedure 
  begin
    ... Draw the frame .... // I can render only in main UI thread
  end;
end;
```

The problem is that when you call `fMyWeRTC.doSomeThink;`, the library **internally call renderFrame in it's own background thread** and **wait its return** (crazy but it's made like this, I can't change it). So here **I enter in a deadlock** :(

What are my option ?

1. Use `queue` instead of `synchronize`? no possible because frame is alive only for the time of renderFrame. I don't also want to spend extra memory and time to duplicate it in memory.
2. Do `fMyWeRTC.doSomeThink` in a background thread (with for example `TAnonymousThread.execute`)? that is quite opaque too, the doc doesn't say if we can call any functions from a background thread (when I tried, I have sometimes some exception). To stay on the safe way I prefer to call everything from the main UI thread

So how you can handle this situation?

Comment: Have you considered moving **all work** (creation etc) with `fMyWeRTC` into thread?

Comment: `if (GetCurrentThreadID = MainThreadID) then WriteFrame else TThread.Synchronize(nil, WriteFrame);`, where `WriteFrame` is a `TProc` initialized prior to the above line.

Comment: @MBO Yes I m considering it now, but seem WEBRTC don't work in background thread (need to investigate more on this)

Comment: @LURD in fact TThread.Synchronize internally do this already, if (GetCurrentThreadID = MainThreadID) then WriteFrame else wait. Here webrtc use it's OWN background thread to fire renderFrame and wait the return in it's own background thread

Comment: `I don't also want to spend extra memory and time to duplicate it in memory.`  Why not?  Did you try this and was it a problem?

Comment: @j yes it's work like this, but a picture of 1920*1080 = 2 Megabytes of memory, and I need to do this on every frame of a video :( seam a big wast :(

Comment: @loki 2MB is nothing.  Even for a 32-bit application with a limited memory space, it's still less than 0.1% of your available memory.  The time to copy that frame would be on the order of a hundred microseconds (about 1% of the available processing time for 60fps video), assuming you keep a frame buffer for this purpose.

Comment: @J... not sure about the speed on mobile, with memory fragmentation, etc... and I need to redraw each frame every 16ms :( but yes in average it's take from 1 to 2 ms to copy

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to get around the deadlock is to avoid `Synchronize` altogether.  We can't know *why* you are deadlocking from the code you've shown, but an option might be to use `Queue` with your own synchronization, ie:

```
Procedure fMyWebRTC.renderFrame(frame: TRTCFrame);
const
  RENDER_TIMEOUT = 1500;  { ms }
var
  LEvent : TEvent;
begin
  LEvent := TEvent.Create;      
  try
    LEvent.ResetEvent;
    TThread.Queue(nil,
      procedure 
      begin
        try
          // Draw Frame
        finally
          LEvent.SetEvent;
        end;
      end);
    LEvent.WaitFor(RENDER_TIMEOUT);
    { can check return value here and branch on failed wait, etc... 
      Be careful that LEvent may be freed below on a failed wait
      before it is used in the queued work above.  Need to handle
      that case yourself.
    }
  finally
    LEvent.Free;
  end;
end;
```